# Put in a web page an image depending on daemon

Tags: javascript, css, image, daemon

I 'm trying to put on my website an image that changes depending on the state of a daemon . Let me explain:
The daemon can return me 2 states when run `service alapma.sh status`:
1_`[FAIL ] /home/pi/alarma.py is not running ... failed!`
2_`[ ok] /home/pi/alarma.py is running`
Depending on whether or not activated want to upload a picture or off.png On.png
I have no idea how to do it since I'm not an expert, but hope to be someday :)

This is the code:
'

```
#!/bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: alarma
# Required-Start: $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop: $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: Put a short description of the service here
# Description: Put a long description of the service here
### END INIT INFO

# Change the next 3 lines to suit where you install your script and what you want to call it
DIR=/home/pi
DAEMON=$DIR/alarma.py
DAEMON_NAME=alarma

# Add any command line options for your daemon here
DAEMON_OPTS=""

# This next line determines what user the script runs as.
# Root generally not recommended but necessary if you are using the Raspberry Pi GPIO from Python.
DAEMON_USER=root

# The process ID of the script when it runs is stored here:
PIDFILE=/var/run/$DAEMON_NAME.pid

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

do_start () {
log_daemon_msg "Starting system $DAEMON_NAME daemon"
start-stop-daemon --start --background --pidfile $PIDFILE --make-pidfile --user $DAEMON_USER --chuid $DAEMON_USER --startas $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_OPTS
log_end_msg $?
}
do_stop () {
log_daemon_msg "Stopping system $DAEMON_NAME daemon"
start-stop-daemon --stop --pidfile $PIDFILE --retry 10
log_end_msg $?
}

case "$1" in

start|stop)
do_${1}
;;

restart|reload|force-reload)
do_stop
do_start
;;

status)
status_of_proc "$DAEMON_NAME" "$DAEMON" && exit 0 || exit $?
;;
*)
echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/$DAEMON_NAME {start|stop|restart|status}"
exit 1
;;

esac
exit 0
```

The solution I've found is that every time I run the web, launch a `sudo service alarma.sh status` and type the image file (On.png or off.png to currentstatus.png) depending on whether it is active or not the daemon. The 2 outputs that can return me the status of the daemon are:
- [ Ok] /home/pi/alarma.py is running .
- [ FAIL] /home/pi/alarma.py is not running ... failed!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide some code so we can see what you have attempted so far?